# How to pass pair of parameters in function

Tags: list-manipulation

I am writing a function with a pair of values `{x,y}`, I have issues when I apply this function to list such as`{{x1,y1},{x2,y1},{x1,y2},{x2,y2}}`.

I have tried with:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1., ArcTan[x, y], 0.];
```

And it only works with f[x,y].

I've also tried to use the pure function with mapping

```
Map[If[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] < 1., ArcTan[#1, #2], 0.] &, {{0.1, 0.2}}]
```

Both are not working as expected. I am so confused about the syntax with other programming languages such as Java, C, etc.

What I want actually to pass a single parameter m, and pair of values {x,y} at the same time:

```
expfun[m_, {x_, y_}] := 
If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 1., 0., 
Cos[m ArcTan[x, y]] + I Sin[m ArcTan[x, y]];
SetAttributes[expfun, Listable];
```

It's not working with e.g:

`expfun[2, {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.1}}]`

Comment: is this what you want?
  expfun[x_, y_] := 
          Block[{m = 2}, 
           If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 1., 0., 
            Cos[m ArcTan[x, y]] + I Sin[m ArcTan[x, y]]]];
        expfun @@@ {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.1}}

Comment: It should work, `f[{x_, y_}] := x + y`, `f[{1, 2}]` -> 3. What do you mean by "it only works with f[x,y]"?

Comment: Perhaps you want `expfun[2,#]&/@{{0.1,0.2},{0.2,0.1}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f[m_Real, lst_List] := 
 Map[If[Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] > 1., Table[0, Length[lst]], 
    Cos[m ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] + 
     I Sin[m ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]] &, lst]
```

Let us check it:

```
f[2., {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.1}}]

(* {-0.6 + 0.8 I, 0.6 + 0.8 I}  *)
```

and

```
f[2., {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}  *)
```

Have fun!